# Extract substring from between two words

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a clean way to extract a substring from between two other substrings.So far I can do it based on targeting a specific character, but not a string. E.g (this doesn't work)

```
 var element = "Firstconstantmystring_lastconstant";
 var mySubString = element.substring(
                            element.lastIndexOf("Firstconstant") + 1,
                            element.lastIndexOf("_lastconstant")
                        );
```

I'm trying to extract "mystring" from the full string. I know that "Firstconstant" and "_lastconstant" will always be the same. Grateful for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression.

```js
var string = 'Firstconstantmystring_lastconstant'
console.log(string.match(/(?<=Firstconstant)[\s\S]*(?=_lastconstant)/))
```

This will return an array with the first element being the result you want if there is a match, or `null` if there is no match.

Resources:

- MDN Reference for `String.prototype.match`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match
- MDN regex cheatsheet: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet

Comment: You should also mention about the performance between substring and regex!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should take the *length* from the first:

```js
var element = "Firstconstantmystring_lastconstant";
var mySubString = element.substring(
                            "Firstconstant".length,
                            element.lastIndexOf("_lastconstant")
                        );
console.log(mySubString);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function substringBetween(s, a, b) {
var p = s.indexOf(a) + a.length;
return s.substring(p, s.indexOf(b, p));
}

var element = "Firstconstantmystring_lastconstant;";
var mySubString = substringBetween(element,'Firstconstant','_lastconstant')

console.log({mySubString })
```